# Attempting to wrangle a dataframe using dplyr so one variable is represented multiple times after putting all columns together

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

...lemme explain.

So I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
pdf_name    fruit_1    fruit_2     fruit_3 
rainer      apple      grapefruit  banana
blue_ridge  kiwi       peach       lemon
mohawk      banana     apple
ozark       banana
shashta     watermelon lemon
```

I would like this dataframe to be a list of the fruit variables side by side with the pdf_name variable in one column. I tried this but it isn't what i want bc i need those pdf's. Let's call the above df "qual_info":

```
qual_info <- qual_info  %>% 
select(c(pdf_name,fruit_1,fruit_2,fruit_3))  %>% 
  gather()
```

I hope to have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
pdf_name    fruit
rainer      apple      
rainer      grapefruit  
rainer      banana
blue_ridge  kiwi  
blue_ridge  peach
blue_ridge  lemon
mohawk      banana  
mohawk      apple
ozark       banana
shashta     watermelon 
shashta     lemon
```

Comment: You need `qual-info %>% gather(key, fruit, starts_with('fruit'), na.rm = TRUE) %>% select(-key) %>% arrange(factor(pdf_name, levels = unique(pdf_name)))`   `select` returns a subset of columns, while in `gather` you need to specify the columns that you need to gather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like @akrun says, use `gather()` and remove `NA` values.

```r
df <- tibble(pdf=letters[1:5],
             fruit1=c('apple','kiwi','banana','banana','watermelon'),
             fruit2=c('grapefruit','peach','apple',NA,NA),
             fruit3=c('banana','lemon',NA,NA,NA))
df

df %>% gather(var,fruit,-pdf) # NA's included

df %>% gather(var,fruit,-pdf,na.rm=T) %>% # remove NA fruit cases
  select(-var) # remove original fruit columns
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   pdf   fruit     
   <chr> <chr>     
 1 a     apple     
 2 b     kiwi      
 3 c     banana    
 4 d     banana    
 5 e     watermelon
 6 a     grapefruit
 7 b     peach     
 8 c     apple     
 9 a     banana    
10 b     lemon
```